# Undefined index: image

Tags: php, file-upload, undefined-index

Why is this not working? Trying to upload file using PHP. File in question is an image just need to store the file path. Trying this code but is not working. Any help?

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="book_create.php" method="POST">
title: <input type="text" name="title"/><br>
authors: <input type="text" name="authors"/><br>
description: <textarea type="text" name="description"></textarea><br>
price: <input type="text" name="price"/><br>
image: <input type="file" name="image"/><br>
content: <input type="file" name="content"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="book_create"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The PHP:

```
if ($_FILES["image"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["image"]["error"] . "<br>";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["image"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["image"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["image"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];
 }
```

Keep getting undefined index error yet used "image"?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing your `enctype` attribute on your form:

```
<form action="book_create.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag